# Is it ok to use in both datagram socket for send and received?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, networking

My class MasterSlaveSynchronize is used both to send and recived hearbeat.
Is it ok to have only one datagram socket that will use to both - send , recieved ?

The 2 method bellow run from time to time and can run simultaneously.

```
void MasterSlaveSynchronize::sendHearBeat() {
    const int HEARBEAT_LEN = 1;
    const char HEARBEAT[1] = { '1' };

    int n = sendto(sock, HEARBEAT, HEARBEAT_LEN, 0,(const struct sockaddr *) &target_, length_);
    if (n < 0)
        printf("Sendto"); //TODO ERR
}

void MasterSlaveSynchronize::recivedHearBeat() {
    char buf[1024];
    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &this_, length_) < 0)
        printf("binding"); //TODO err
    while (1) {
        int n = recvfrom(sock, buf, 1024, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &target_,&length_);
        if (n < 0)
            printf("recvfrom"); //TODO ER
        //TODO update got hearbeat
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's fine (indeed expected) to use the same socket for `sendto` and `recvfrom`.

However your `recivedHearBeat()` function never exits.  That's OK, if it's running in a separate thread.

Comment: Yep , sure its running in a different thread. the class is used both as client to send heartbeat and server that received hearbeat. Is it Ok to use the same port for send and received? and last one (and stupid) - dosnt bind of the socket bind it to a specific usage (ip, port) ?

Comment: yes, the `bind` does make the socket specific to the one (ip, port) which is then used for both send and receive.  That `bind` needs to happen before the `sendto` function gets called.

Comment: but for the sendHearBeat i dont need to use the bind.

Comment: @user1495181 no, once it's done on the socket it applies in both directions.

Comment: I dont need it at all for send from client to server. i can use sendHearBeat method with only create socket without any bind and it will work as a client.